# is there a way to get rid of the 1-point-perspective section affected by low FOV?

Tags: graphics, 3d, perspective

I'm working on a 3d engine in Desmos, and if I turn the FOV down too far, it gets weird. Is there a way to keep it from doing that?
Here's the link:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rsfn1x5aou

Comment: just from a quick look at the result it looks like your geometry is hitting the znear and even get behind your focal point of camera ... so You probably need `Frustrum culling`  so do not render stuff outside Frustrum (`znear,zfar` range).

Comment: Thank you! Ill try that.

Answer (score 0):

I am reasonably sure this is a effect of your specific rendering engine, i have a similar project and no mirroring occurs until FOV goes negative, here is my rederer:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cfj2hyjpbw

Comment: Since this does not provide a sure solution, I think this answer would be better placed as a comment